# transfer vlan from one cisco switch to an other through a central cisco switch

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, cisco-catalyst

I can't figure out how to pass one vlan from one switch to an other:
Let's say, I have 2 valns:
Vlan 1 and Vlan 2

3 cisco switches:

1. Cisco Catalyst 3560g (central switch)
2. Cisco SG-300 (with native Vlan 2)
3. Cisco SG-300 (with native Vlan 1)

They are connected this way:
2 -> 1 <- 3

On switch 3, there is one device connected, that needs to be connected to the Vlan 2.
I added Vlan 2 on the port, where that device is connected and on the port, that's connected to the switch 1.

But the device, connected to the Vlan 2 port convigured on the switch 3 still can't ping the devices from Vlan 2, that are connected to the switch 2.

---

How do I need to configure the related ports for Vlan to start working?

Comment: The connections between the switches need to be trunks, but traffic from one VLAN to another must be routed with a router or routing configured on a layer-3 switch.

Comment: I've checked. All the ports are trunks.
Switches: 1 and 2 both have IP addresses configured for VLAN 2.
Does the switch 3 have to have IP configured for the VLAN 2 also, or it should work without the IP?
Right now, the VLAN 2 on switch 3 is configured without an address.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seams you are need to Configure InterVLAN Routing - I believe it can be done with 3560 you have. Try ip routing command - and if possible go to https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/inter-vlan-routing/41860-howto-L3-intervlanrouting.html to get full instruction

Answer (score 0):

Trunking VLANs enables each of them to span multiple switches.

You need to configure all four ports between the switches as **trunk ports** (assuming they're access ports right now). If they already are in trunk mode you need to permit the VLANs 1 & 2 across those trunks.

If you can't sort it out please add the switch configs to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Transferring the VLANs from a central switch can be accomplished by using Vlan Trunking Protocol (VTP). The links between the switches must be trunks for this to work.

To make a switchport a trunk (I use Gi0/1 in this example). Provided Dynamic Trunking Protocol (DTP) has not been turned off, the other side of the link should come up as a trunk as well. This example also allows only vlans 1 and 2, but you can change the range to suit your network.

```
en
conf t
int Gi0/1
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-2
```

Then to enable VTP...

On the Central switch:

```
en
conf t
vtp domain something.ext
vtp version 2
```

On the other switches:

```
en
conf t
vtp domain something.ext
vtp mode client
```

HTH

Matthew

"When you teach someone what you know, you gain a greater understanding of the subject, which increases your own retention of the knowledge."